# Returning a promise in a Redux thunk with typescript

Tags: typescript, redux-thunk

I am getting this typescript error:  `Property 'then' does not exist on type 'ThunkAction<Promise<boolean>, IinitialState, undefined, any>'.`

Please help!

How I have configured my store and included the type:

```
    return createStore(
      rootReducer,
      intialState,
      require('redux-devtools-extension').composeWithDevTools(
        applyMiddleware(
          thunk as ThunkMiddleware<IinitialState, any>,
          require('redux-immutable-state-invariant').default()
        )
      )
```

Action Creator:

```
type ThunkResult<R> = ThunkAction<R, IinitialState, undefined, any>;

export function anotherThunkAction(): ThunkResult<Promise<boolean>> {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }
}
```

then in my component I have a prop interface:

```
interface IProps {
  anotherThunkAction: typeof anotherThunkAction;
}
```

Then:

```
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.anotherThunkAction().then(() => {console.log('hello world')})
  }
```

Connect where I am using react-i18next as well:

```
export default translate('manageInventory')(
  connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    {
      anotherThunkAction
    }
  )(ManageInventory)
);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you're dispatching things properly... you are calling your action without passing it through the store.

If you call the action directly, you'll get back :

```
ThunkAction<Promise<boolean>, IinitialState, undefined, any>
```

Which as tsc is telling you, doesn't have a `then` function. When you run something through `dispatch` it turns `ThunkResult<R>` into `R`

You haven't shown how you `connect` your component to the store - but I think this is where the problem lies.  Here is a sample:

```
type MyThunkDispatch = ThunkDispatch<IinitialState, undefined, any>

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: MyThunkDispatch) => ({
  anotherThunkAction: () => dispatch(anotherThunkAction())
})

connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyComponent)
```

This will add `anotherThunkAction` to `props` and you can call it and it'll call into your action properly and return the promise.

Comment: Thanks @tswaters, this helped me realize I needed to provide more details.  I updated my question.  Sheesh there are a lot of pieces involved when wiring this up.  Correct me if I am wrong, but I believe since I am adding the type in my applyMiddleware function, I do not need to add the type in all of my mapDispatchToProps functions.

Comment: @jfbloom22 you are correct.  I'm also running into the same thing, and trying to figure out the best way to type it.  I honestly think that redux-thunk and redux just might not have correct typings... 

I'm able to get everything typed except the `mapDispatchToProps` function

Comment: Any idea to fix this? const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: ThunkDispatch) => ({
  dispatch: (arg: any) => dispatch(dispatch(arg))
}) this.props
      .dispatch(createClient(this.state.name))
      .then(client => {
        this.props.history.push(`/clients/${client.payload.id}`);
      })